# natbib, multiple bibliographies

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I've completed my master thesis but my professor is quite picky and told me to use the ecta style for the bibliography; I have one bibliography for books and articles and one for websites and I am using multibib.

Ecta style must be used with natbib, as far as I have [read](http://tug.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/economic/ecta.bst).
The fact is that using ecta + natbib the books bibliography works fine while I can't get the website bibliography because I get the nasty error of not compatible bibliography, even though I use plainnat for websites.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage,twoside,openright,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}                                      
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                    
\usepackage{hyperref}                                                
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{varioref} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}                                    
\newcites{web}{Useful websites}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\blindtext

\blindtext

\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\bibliography{biblio}
\nocite{*}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}

\bibliographystyleweb{plainnat}
\bibliographyweb{web}
\nociteweb{*}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Useful websites}

\end{document}
```

Here's one entry of my biblio.bib

```
@incollection{Akallabeth,
address = {New York, USA},
booktitle = {The Silmarillion},
editor = {Tolkien, Christopher},
publisher = {Mariner Books},
author = {Tolkien, John Ronald Reuel},
title = {Akallabeth - The Downfall of Numenor},
year = {2014},
tags = "MasterThesis"
}
```

and one from web.bib

```
@misc{wikiicd10,
note = {\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICD-10}},
title = {Wikipedia - \textit{“ICD-10”}},
year = {2015},
tags = "master"
}
```

Yea, I have even tried to give the year to the websites, with no useful result.

Comment: Your example doesn't load natbib, if I add it (*before* multibib) and move hyperref and bookmark to the end of the preamble I can compile without error.

Comment: oh yes, sorry I did not realized I didn't load natbib;
Yes, now it works: so the trick was just on putting natbib before multibib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to loading `natbib` (before `multibib`), you may also want to edit the `@misc`-type entries a bit to take better advantage of the fact that you're using the `plainnat` bibliography type.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@incollection{Akallabeth,
  author       = "Tolkien, John Ronald Reuel",
  title        = "Akallabeth---The Downfall of Numenor",
  year         = 2014,
  editor       = "Tolkien, Christopher",
  booktitle    = "The Silmarillion",
  publisher    = "Mariner Books",
  address      = "New York, USA",
  tags         = "MasterThesis",
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{web.bib}
@misc{wikiicd10,
  author       = "Wikipedia",
  title        = "{ICD-10}",
  year         = 2015,
  url          = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICD-10",
  tags         = "master",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage,twoside,openright,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{web}{Useful websites}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip\noindent
% Generate two citation callouts
\citet{Akallabeth},
\citeweb{wikiicd10}

\cleardoublepage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\bibliography{biblio}

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Useful websites}
\bibliographystyleweb{plainnat}
\bibliographyweb{web}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, yes of course, that was supposed to be the next step once I had figured out how to make two bibliographies work :)
But, why does natbib go before multibib? I didn't read it anywhere!

Comment: @Ale - The key about loading `natbib` when using `multibib` is that all citation callouts must use either authoryear style or numeric style, but not a mixture of the two. Since the `ecta` style can only produce authoryear-type citation callouts, it's important to load `natbib` with the option `authoryear` -- `plainnat` can produce either type of callout, and it's important to be clear about the style to be used.

Comment: I want to print Author Publication and bibliography. I tried your code. But in my case, second citation fro web.bib is not printed. Kindly help me