# Preventing multiple loaded bibliographies from mixing

Tags: bibliographies, pdftex, citing, natbib, article

Assume a TeX document (`\documentclass{article}`) with two separate bibliographies on different pages that are handled by `natbib`.

The first bibliography (`My_Large_Bibliography.bib`) is called as follows:

```
\section*{Appendix 1: List of References}
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}
\bibliographystyle{apalike-refs}
\bibliography{My_Large_Bibliography.bib}
\endgroup
\clearpage

\section*{Appendix 2: Some Text}
Hey y'all! See my amazing publications of 2021 \citep[e.g.,][]{Shared_publication}.
% Do some magical citation reset here.
```

The second bibliography (`My_Top10_Articles.bbl`) is pre-compiled, has a different bibliography style, and is called as follows:

```
\section*{Appendix 3: Curriculum Vitae}
\subsection*{Top-10 Publications}
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}
\input{My_Top10_Articles.bbl}
\endgroup
```

Several of the bibliography entries in `My_Large_Bibliography.bib` also exist in `My_Top10_Articles.bbl`. When I cite one of the references in Appendix 2 (i.e., ***before*** the second bibliography is even called), the in-line citations are formatted according to the second bibliography (and, in addition, messed up).

Is there any way to prevent the bibliographies from mixing with regarding to in-line citations? For example, is there a way to reset or clear the loaded bibliography at the end of Appendix 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be advisable to create two separate bibliographies without precompiling a `.bbl` file, for example using the `multibib` package with `natbib` as in, e.g., [natbib, multiple bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289435/natbib-multiple-bibliographies) or `chapterbib` with `natbib` as in, e.g., [Sectionbib, natbib and separate bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419969/sectionbib-natbib-and-separate-bibliographies).

However, if you do not want to actually cite anything from the second bibliography and you want to continue using the precompiled `.bbl` file, then you might have some success in redefining the bibliography-specific commands to behave like normal paragraphs or lists. This would remove duplicate cite keys and prevents later bibliographies from interfering with the appearance of citations in the main document.

Concretely, for an author-year style this means disabling `\begin{bibliography}` and `\end{bibliography}` and redefining `\bibitem` to be a paragraph with hanging indent and a bit of parskip. For a numeric style you can instead redefine the `bibliography` environment to be `enumerate` and `\bibitem` to be `\item`, using the `enumitem` package to format the entries as `[n]`. The exact details depend on which bibliography styles you use, but an example is the following:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mainreferences.bib}
@article{myarticle,
    author = {John Doe},
    title = {Shared publication which has a very long title so it wraps to the next line to check if indentation works},
    journal = {Shared Journal},
    year = {2021}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{precompiled.bbl}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi

\bibitem[Doe(2021)]{myarticle}
John Doe.
\newblock Shared publication which has a very long title so it wraps to the next line to check if indentation works.
\newblock \emph{Shared Journal}, 2021.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\noindent My article: \cite{myarticle}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mainreferences}

\section*{Second bibliography}
\parskip=6pt
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[2][]{\par\noindent\hangindent1Em}
\def\thebibliography#1{\relax}
\def\endthebibliography{\relax}
\input{precompiled.bbl}

\section*{Second bibliography with numeric style}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={[\arabic*]},leftmargin=*}
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[2][]{\item}
\def\thebibliography#1{\enumerate}
\def\endthebibliography{\endenumerate}
\input{precompiled.bbl}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that you may not be able to recreate the exact format of your precompiled bibliography easily using this method. In that case it is recommended to create 'official' multiple bibliographies as in the questions linked above.

Comment: Thank you for this insightful answer!